# Duplicate SQLite database in webapp

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database in a mobile webapp, the only problem is Safari creates a new database every time I refresh the website.
Here is my code:

```
var databaseOptions = {
fileName : "todo_database",
version : "1.0",
displayName : "todoDB",
maxSize : 1024
};

var database = openDatabase(databaseOptions.fileName, databaseOptions.version, 
databaseOptions.displayName, databaseOptions.maxSize);

database.transaction(function(transaction) {
            alert('table created');
            transaction.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todos (" + 
            "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "todo TEXT NOT NULL,description TEXT,date DATE);");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually was not a problem with the code, it seems to be a bug in Safari for Windows, if I close the browser only one database remains and with all the information.