# Safari/Chrome created duplicate webSQL database on browser refresh

Tags: html

I'm creating a mobile web application using HTML5, CSS 3 and Javascript. Currently I am testing this in both Google Chrome and Safari desktop browsers as I will eventually publish this application to both iOS and Android devices.

During testing the database operations are working as expected (which is fantastic) BUT each time I refresh the web page the Database that was originally created is duplicated (after a number of page refreshes the number of databases grows to a silly number) and I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I thought that the browser would check whether the database existed (and create it if it doesn't) or open the database (if the check is positive for the database existing). The following code is used to create the database:

```
var Database = function(){
this.db     = false;
this.dbName     = 'Stores';
this.dbVersion  = '1.0';
this.display    = 'Stores';
this.dbSize     = 5000000;
this.resultSet      = [];
}


Database.prototype = {

initialiseDatabase : function(){
this.db = openDatabase(this.dbName, this.dbVersion, this.display, this.dbSize);
return this;
}
}
```

This class method (not strictly a class in JS but for want of terminology it's accepted) is then called only once in a front-end view with the following code:

db.initialiseDatabase();

Like I stated earlier, the code works fine EXCEPT for when the page is refreshed in both Google Chrome and Safari. When this happens the database that already exists is replicated with each page refresh.

Is anyone able to provide any suggestions/pointers on what I might be doing wrong or could do to prevent this from happening? I looked at this post: [Duplicate SQLite database in webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201700/duplicate-sqlite-database-in-webapp) but I'm finding this happening on both browsers mentioned above on Mac OS X 10.7.

Thanks in advance to anyone who may be able to give me a heads up :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening?

Comment: I've noticed this too. Not sure whether the browser is just incorrectly reporting the duplicates.